# How can I transform values in RestKit mappings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, key-value-coding

Say I'm getting this response from an API endpoint:

```
{ "tags": [1, 5, 9] }
```

Now, I want to store `"tags"` as a bitmask on my object, not an array (for whatever reason...this is a contrived example). I want to do something like this:

```
[whateverMapping addAttributeMapping:@"tags"
             withTransformationBlock:^NSNumber *(NSArray *tags) { ... }];
```

But I've gone up and down the documentation and I can't find what the canonical way to perform this is.

My current (crappy) workaround is to have a category called `RestKitTransformers` that implements methods like `setTagsRK:` (and corresponding getters for serialization) so that RestKit is none the wiser that this transformation is taking place.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: As of today, this seems to be an open feature request: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/294